# Android SearchView can't go to the SearchResultsActivity

Tags: android, searchview

I am following the google android reference https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html to implement my app's SearchView, but when entry completes and I click the right-bottom in the keyboard,it doesn't go to the SearchResultsActivity without error info.

My SearchView is in NotesActivity, and when user type the keyword complete,it will go to SearchResultsActivity with a recyclerView in it.
Here is my manifest.xml :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".notes.NotesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".search.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and this is the NotesActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Here is the SearchResultsActivity's main code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        mKeyword = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mKeyword)) {
            mPresenter.loadNotes(mKeyword);
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, R.string.search_empty_keyword, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

menu/main.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

xml/searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Please guide.

Comment: Can you show the source code for SearchResultsActivity?

Comment: Oh,sorry ,but I print a log in the SearchResultsActivity.onCreate() function，but it doesn't print anything,so I don't show the SearchResultsActivity code.I will add it.

Comment: You can try to override onNewIntent() and see if that function gets called

Comment: I have override onNewIntent() already, it doesn't get called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing from the **SearchResultsActivity** the

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

and the

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

in the **NotesActivity** the linkage is done via

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
```

The *searchable* is related to the activity where the search dialog is displayed and the *default_searchable* to define which one to use for delivering the searches.

and the proper documentation for it is here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Thank you for solve my question, but I still don't know what's the difference between android.app.searchable and android.app.default_searchable. Can you help me?

Comment: I added more explanation in the answer